# Gunicorn error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'"

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to do nginx on aws with this film [Deploy a Django web app with Nginx to Amazon EC2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7O1H9kr1CsA&ab_channel=CloudWithDjango) but im stuck on 24 min...

When i'm trying to check gunicorn status with

```
sudo supervisorctl status
```

i got massage

```
FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

I found error log and this is what it said

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'
[2023-06-18 16:51:55 +0000] [16414] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 16414)
[2023-06-18 16:51:55 +0000] [16411] [WARNING] Worker with pid 16413 was terminated due to signal 15
[2023-06-18 16:51:55 +0000] [16411] [WARNING] Worker with pid 16414 was terminated due to signal 15
[2023-06-18 16:51:55 +0000] [16411] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2023-06-18 16:51:55 +0000] [16411] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
[2023-06-18 16:51:57 +0000] [16415] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-06-18 16:51:57 +0000] [16415] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/ubuntu/myapp/app.sock (16415)
[2023-06-18 16:51:57 +0000] [16415] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-06-18 16:51:57 +0000] [16416] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16416
[2023-06-18 16:51:57 +0000] [16417] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16417
[2023-06-18 16:51:57 +0000] [16418] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16418
[2023-06-18 16:51:57 +0000] [16416] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/init.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/init.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/init.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
```

All i understand there is problem with CKEditor plugin. I am working with virtual environment and ckeditor is installed there. In projects settings.py 'ckeditor' is in INSTALLED_APPS.

Anyone has an idea what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with service configuration.
Please check the following to solve the issue

1. Gunicorn should be running successfully directly. You can check this with  [gunicorn](https://pypi.org/project/gunicorn/)
2. Service configuration uses the same virtual environment where package is installed. to check that check the service file, usually its location in linux is /etc/systemd/system/